# Trouble formatting data with bs4 and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to get rid of the html around the prices but whatever I've tried hasn't worked.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en"
result = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
prices = data.find_all(attrs={"class":"no-wrap", "class" : "td-price price text-right pl-0"})

a = np.asarray(prices[0:10])
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(df.text)
```

the data is coming out like this:

```
\n  [$36,015.04]  \n
1  \n   [$2,499.62]  \n
2  \n       [$1.00]  \n
3  \n     [$378.24]  \n
4  \n       [$1.00]  \n
5  \n       [$1.11]  \n
6  \n   [$0.620196]  \n
7  \n      [$93.38]  \n
8  \n      [$68.86]  \n
9  \n      [$18.50]  \n
```

I'm trying t get rid of the \n's, brackets, and dollar signs

The error message is

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a 
list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is 
deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the 
ndarray.
```

I'm very new to using python so sorry if this is an obvious question.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. First, your code `{"class":"no-wrap", "class" : "td-price price text-right pl-0"}` creates a python dict, but a python dict cannot have more than one key-value pair with the same key, so the second instance will silently overwrite the first and you'll get `{"class" : "td-price price text-right pl-0"}` instead.
Then, you don't mention what you're doing to transform the output, and don't say which code line generates the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
prices = data.find_all(attrs={"class":"no-wrap", "class" : "td-price price text-right pl-0"})
prices = [price.text.replace("\n","").strip() for price in prices]
```

that second line will reiterate through the prices list and remove all the \n (which are line breaks) and .strip will remove any spaces at the start or end of your items.